# Redis class client is closed

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, redis

this is my Redis.ts

```
import { createClient } from "redis";

class RedisClient {
  client;

  constructor() {
    this.client = createClient();
    this.client.on("connect", (connect) =>
      console.log("Redis Client connected", connect)
    );
  }

  set = async (key: string, value: any) => {
    await this.client.set(key, value);
  };

  get = async (key: string) => {
    return await this.client.get(key);
  };

  disconnect = async () => {
    await this.client.disconnect();
  };
}

export const Redis = new RedisClient();
```

and while exporting Redis class getting error `The client is closed` This is my `VController.ts`

```
import { Redis } from "../utilities/Redis";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
class VController {
index = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {    
    Redis.set('user', {name: "somename"});
    console.log(Redis);
    // more code goes here...
  };
}
```

Error
return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());
^
ClientClosedError: The client is closed

Unable to set value in Redis, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there! According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis), the `client` needs to be explicitly connected by way of the `connect()` function in order for the commands to be sent to the target Redis node(s):

```
class RedisClient {
  // ...
  connect = () => this.client.connect();
  // ...
}
```

And in your calling code:

```
// ...
await Redis.connect();
Redis.set('user', json.stringify({name: "somename"}));
// ...
```

Comment: Yes, I have resolved it basically, i have to set data using json.stringify() and the connect method explicitly called within the constructor